# Java animations and background color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe, paint

I'm creating an animation in an undercoated JFrame. I am wanting to change the background color of the JFrame, however it does not change. Currently the animation is playing, and I am allowed to move my JFrame, but the background color of the JFrame is the default light gray.

```
        mover = new javax.swing.JPanel(); // allows me to move the JFrame, also it acts as the colored background of the JFrame

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        mover.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51)); // dark gray color
        mover.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.MatteBorder(null));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout moverLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mover);
        mover.setLayout(moverLayout);
        moverLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            moverLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 698, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        moverLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            moverLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 498, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        getContentPane().add(mover);
        mover.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 500);

        pack();
```

I am not sure how much more information you need to help me, as I am not sure where the problem is.

Here is my double buffer code in case needed

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        draw(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        b.draw(g);
        repaint();
    }
```

Comment: How did you try to set your background color?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0):

After making sure that your panel has opacity set to true (`JPanel.setOpaque(boolean)`), override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` rather than `paint(Graphics g)` and call `super.paintComponent(g)` as your first statement. The opacity setting will make sure that your background is painted.